# FabricJs: Font does not update after changing Text

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Is this an issue/bug ?
try on the offical demo site:

http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink
OR
http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts

1. select Textbox with a text
2. make sure cursor inside Textbox
3. ctrl+a to mark all Text
4. overwrite the old Text with some new words (while marking the old text)

After new input, you are not able to change font-Family anymore or other Font settings like font size. Shadows still works.

?? why this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Good catch.

in the above examples, if you select textbox and see console

```
canvas.getActiveObject().styles
```

This will return the object of multiple styles becase those styles are assigned to per char of string/textbox.

If you want to change the fontFamily or any style after changing text.  just asign styles = null as below.

You can test this in http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink also in developer tool.

> `canvas.getActiveObject().styles = null`

[image]